# How to insert image in pdf using prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

I am using rails 4. I want to display an image in pdf, so I install prawn gem file and my code is

```
def index
  text "something"
  image "#{Rails.root}/images/logo.jpg"
end
```

but i getting an error as `undefined method image`

Comment: Does it work if you take the `image` line out?  Ie is prawn installed correctly?

Comment: I installed prawn and their dependencies, but i still getting an error

Comment: With just the "text" line?  If so then this question should be about installing prawn, not about images in prawn, since you have a more fundamental problem.

Comment: You have to create a `class YourClass < Prawn::Document`

Comment: @magurit the document recommend deriving from the view Mixin: `class YourClass < Prawn::View` instead of `Document` - it avoids naming collisions while still providing the same benefits of deriving from `Document`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, prawn give undefined method image. So you can use this way.

In test.pdf.prawn file.

```
pdf.image "#{Rails.root}/images/logo.jpg"
```

You can also apply position and width to 
as:

```
pdf.image "#{Rails.root}/images/logo.jpg", :at => [50,450], :width => 450
```

Comment: Agree, just an appointment, use `ASSETS_PATH.join('logo.jpg')`.